# Firebase XMPP Protocol Vs HTTP Protocol

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I am planning to use Firebase Cloud Messaging with my Android and IOS APP.

In Firebase there are two type of protocol HTTP and XMPP, so my question is when to use which protocol. In which scenario which protocol performs the best.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: *Also as Firebase not support in the emulator* ... where did you read this?

Comment: Someone said that Firebase Cloud Messaging not push message to Android emulator. I may be wrong. Is it support in the emulator?

Comment: Someone said that Earth is flat ... *Is it support in the emulator?* why don't you test it?

Comment: I am not and Android developer bro I am just asking for sending push message from the back-end to the APP that's why.

Comment: I'f you've never used either, I'd start with the HTTP API. In fact: I started with that one myself and have yet to use the XMPP API. :-)   That said: such recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow, since the choice is highly subjective. So I'll vote to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what source you have got that Firebase does not work in emulator!! I am developing an app using genymotion emulator and it works good. Also about HTTP and XMPP what protocol you use depending on the server you will be using. HTTP is simple to use and a lot of people go with it while XMPP is complicated to implement on the device and server as well.
But XMPP may be harder it supports downstream and upstream messages means you can also send a message from a device to your server. But XMPP is good as it does not take a lot of charge and battery.
But nearly everyone use HTTP. And implement upstream messages by your own implementation!!

Comment: Sorry for that information an Android developer said that it don't work in Android emulator. I might be wrong, I don't have enough knowledge in Android development. I am asking the question due to some back-end development to send push notification from the server side. Thank you for the information. If I want to send batches of push notification to lot of client APP is there any specific advantages in terms of scale ability or performance benefit if I use XMPP protocol. Currently there is no need of upstream messages in the APP.

Comment: XMPP is better only if you expect your client to get a lot of messages from your server ex messaging app,chatting apps because it is lightweight and charge friendly so battery life of your users will be much saved for many messages when your users are chatting but if you only intent to respond to something in your users devices just go with HTPP. simple and most used!!

Answer (score 0):

IMO this does not matter a lot pick the one which u feel more comfortable with.

Only thing I can state is that XMPP is protocol created for communication so if your notifications consist of short frequent messages pick this one, otherwise pick HTTP, which is more commonly used

Sincerely I have experience just with HTTP and it works really well

Answer (score 0):

According to my view, use HTPP.  because XMPP requires HTTP more than HTPP requires XMPP.

XMPP is an open standard technology protocol used to presence indicator and instant messaging, while for HTTP had good features and the same time it works better than XMPP.